# How to make a dynamic span for a timechart?

Tags: splunk

I have a splunk dashboard whose query looks like so:

```
index=my_index sourcetype=cloudwatch_log responseTime | timechart span=5m avg(responseTime) as responseTime
```

The dashboard has a time input. I want the span in the above query to update based on the time input chosen such that the span is always, say, 10% of the time range. As an example, the user chooses 15minutes, the span would be 1.5m. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[RichG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227420/richg)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65097682/4418) is correct - but doesn't address your core issue, which is wanting to set a specific `span=` for any given selected timeframe.

If you're doing this on a "splunk dashboard", you can control *a lot* about how your search works by using tokens.

#### Create a custom time selector as a dropdown that you populate with your *own* choices

I do this to control just what users can select.

You might have, for example:

- 10m
- 1h
- 1d
- 1w
- 1mo

#### Make those are *their own static entries* in a dropdown:

[image]

[image]

Then edit the source, and add some [`condition`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.0/Viz/tokens#Conditional_operations_with_form_inputs) entries that set a *second token* you'll use in your search later:

[image]

#### In your search, use the tokens thusly:

[image]

You can now control both the *timeframe used*, **and** the *span displayed* in your visualization.

Of course - name your tokens better, make as many entries as you need, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the `span=5m` option then `timechart` will choose a span that's appropriate for the selected time range.

Comment: ah, but no way to set a consistent %?

Comment: Groups can be by count or by time, but not percent.  You can specify a number of bins using `bins=10` so each is 10%, but that's a maximum, not a fixed number.  `timechart` may choose a different number depending on the data.

Comment: @yalpsideman - the way to set a "consistent %" is the method I provided. `timechart`, on its own, determines the 'optimum' number of groupings based on the time range given.